# How do I combine two dictionaries with similar keys but different values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

For example, I have

```
a = {'bob': [1, 2], 'bill': [3, 4], 'steve': [1]}
```

and I want to add this to another dictionary

```
b = {'bob': [4], 'bill': [7]}
```

to create

```
b = {'bob': [1, 2, 4], 'bill': [3, 4, 7], 'steve': [1]}
```

I tried looping through a and adding the list to the values of the list from b to a, but it isn't working with basic list addition methods. Thanks in advance.

Comment: something like `a[key] += b[key]` ? You might want to check if the key is in second dict with `try/catch`

Comment: _"I tried..."_: It is better to show what you tried, and how it failed, as a [mre], instead of describing what you did. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Providing a MRE that is both minimal and reproducible will allow you to ask a _specifc_ question.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
def add_dicts(a, b):
    return {
        k: a.get(k, []) + b.get(k, [])
        for k in a | b
    }


result = add_dicts(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension, iterating over a union of the keys from both dictionaries. Using `get` will let us default to an empty list if either dictionary lacks the key in question. This avoids a `KeyError` exception.

```
>>> {k: a.get(k, []) + b.get(k, []) for k in a.keys() | b.keys()}
{'steve': [1], 'bob': [1, 2, 4], 'bill': [3, 4, 7]}
```

Without explicitly calling `keys`:

```
{k: a.get(k, []) + b.get(k, []) for k in a | b}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code will merge them in the way you want:

```
a = {'bob': [1, 2], 'bill': [3, 4], 'steve': [1]}
b = {'bob': [4], 'bill': [7]}

def merge(a, b):
    for k, l in a.items():
        b[k] = l +  b.get(k, [])

merge(a, b)
print(b)
```

```
# {'bob': [1, 2, 4], 'bill': [3, 4, 7], 'steve': [1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c = {key: a.get(key,[]) + b.get(key, [])  for key in a|b}
```

It's unclear what you want to do if the lists are intersecting

So if you want only new items then this

```
c = {key: list(set(a.get(key,[])) | set(b.get(key, [])))  for key in a|b}
```